# bring back gray dropbox icon

Tags: panel, dropbox, top-bar

So, on ubuntu 20 and ubuntu 22, the dropbox icon on the top bar is always white.

[image]

I remember, on ubuntu 18, it was only white, when it was connected to the internet and was syncing or was fully synced.
If the status was *Starting* or *Paused* or *Not connected to the internet*, it was grayed out.

Is there a way to bring ^that back? Thanks.